# Bootstrap- jQueryvalidator plugin isn't working with modals

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I want to validate my form input (in a boostrap modal) but it isn't working. It works great without modal but I don't know what'swrong with modal.

When I enter something in form and press Redeem then it just redirects to form action attribute.  Here is my code:

```
<div id= "promo" class= "modal fade" >
<div class ="modal-dialog" >
<div class = "modal-content">
<div class= "modal-header" >
<button type= "button" class ="close" data-dismiss ="modal" aria-hidden ="true" >&times; </button>
<h4 class ="modal-title"> Redeem Kwik Code</h4>
</div>
<div class= "modal-body" >
<p>If you have any Kwik Code or promo code, you may enter it here to redeem free credits or free recharge. Do like us on Facebook to be updated with Kwik codes!</p>

<script>
$('#redeemp').validate({
rules: {
   promo: {
   required: true
   }
},
submitHandler: function (form) {
    $.ajax({
        type: $(form).attr('method'),
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        data: $(form).serialize()
    })
    .done(function (response) {
    $('#alert').html(response);
    });
    return false; // required to block normal submit since you used ajax
 },
            highlight: function(e) {
                $(e).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error")
            },
            unhighlight: function(e) {
                $(e).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error")
            },
            errorElement: "span",
            errorClass: "help-block",
            errorPlacement: function(e, t) {
                if (t.parent(".input-group").length) {
                    e.insertAfter(t.parent())
                } else {
                    e.insertAfter(t)
                }
            }
 });
</script>

<form id="redeemp" action="checkPromo.php" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
<div class="row">
<div id='display-alerts' class="col-lg-12">
</div> <!--alerts-->
</div> <!--row-->
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="promo" placeholder="Enter code here.." name = "promo" >
</div> <!--colmd class-->
</div> <!--formgroup-->
<br>
</div>
<div class= "modal-footer">
<button type= "button" class ="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" >Close</button>
<button  type="submit" class="btn btn-success submit">Redeem</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

*P.S* I have included all the required plugin files.

Comment: Can you provide an online demo such as code snippet or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initialising the scripts before the form.

```
Put all the <scripts> after the </form>
```

Just: You should not give ID "promo" to multiple elements.

Here is your working code: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/8930/